# PHP Loop days from a date and create an array

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, foreach

I try to grade from a foreach to form an array ... unfortunately I understand it not again.

```
$date = new DateTime('last sunday');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($date, $interval, 7, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

foreach ( $period as $dt ){
    echo $dt->format( "d.m.Y\n" )."<br>";
}
```

The array should be picturing so

```
$dat = array(
    "Monday" => $dt->format("d.m.Y \ n"), 
    "Tuesday" => $dt->format("d.m.Y \ n"), 
    "Wednesday" => $dt->format("d.m.Y \ n"), 
    "Thursday" => $dt->format("d.m.Y \ n"), 
    "Friday" => $dt->format("d.m.Y \ n"), 
    "Saturday" => $dt->format("d.m.Y \ n"), 
    "Sunday" => $dt->format("d.m.Y \ n") 
);
```

how do I do it in the foreach? can someone please help me?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just format the keys as day name and assign it on the foreach loop. Example:

```
$date = new DateTime('last sunday');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($date, $interval, 7, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
$dat = array();
foreach($period as $dt) {
    $dat[$dt->format('l')] = $dt->format('d.m.Y');
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dat);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => 30.06.2014
    [Tuesday] => 01.07.2014
    [Wednesday] => 02.07.2014
    [Thursday] => 03.07.2014
    [Friday] => 04.07.2014
    [Saturday] => 05.07.2014
    [Sunday] => 06.07.2014
)
```